# PHP and Django on same Apache server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have an apache server that is being shared with other people. Others are using PHP and I am using Django with Python3.

I am trying to set it up so that any request to www.myweb.com goes to Apache and PHP site will handle that. But anything with www.myweb.com/dj/anything will come to django. For example, www.myweb.com/dj/products should be handled by django and www.myweb.com/products should be handled by PHP site.

I have added this to my apache2.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /dj/ /var/www/html/dj/tools/tools/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/dj/tools
```

However, only www.myweb.com/dj is forwarded to Django. www.myweb.com/dj/products is not forwarded to Django, it goes to Apache and I get Apache's 404.

I have url entries in my urls.py to match with products:

```
url (r'^products$', 'app.baseproduct_view.baseproduct'),
url (r'^$', 'app.base_view.base'),
```

I found a matching post on stack overflow and tried WSGIScriptAliasMatch but no luck.

Let me know if you have any suggestions. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you remove the trailing slash from dj: `WSGIScriptAlias /dj /var/www/...wsgi.py`?

Comment: Wow, that was a quick fix. Muchas Gracias! Can you explain how the trailing slash is making the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the trailing slash from `/dj/`, turning it in to a *file path* and not a *directory path*

The `/` makes a big difference. It essentially makes it a directory mapping:

> Where the target is a **directory-path**, URLs with a case-sensitive
>   (%-decoded) path beginning with URL-path **will be mapped to scripts
>   contained in the indicated directory**.

However, if you remove the trailing `/`:

> Where the target is a **file-path**, URLs with a case-sensitive
>   (%-decoded) path beginning with URL-path **will be mapped to the script
>   defined by the file-path**.

Once you remove the `/`, all paths are send to the `wsgi.py` handler (because its mapping to a file, not a directory), and thus django's url machinery can start working.

If you keep the `/`, then Apache is trying to find a file `/dj/products` in the directory path.